# How to replace empty except block?

Tags: delphi, exception, try-except

Browsing some legacy code, I encounter some "empty" except blocks. They all were implemented for a similar reason, that is to handle a conversion from a text in TEdit to a numeric value. As the TEdit might be empty, there should be no error message in such a situation:

```
procedure TmyForm.EditExit(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ...  
  try
    _value := StrToFloat(Edit.Text);
  except
  end; 
  ...
end;
```

That works well but not really a good practice I guess. Is there a better way to get the same behavior?

Comment: Yes I could check every `TEdit` value in every `OnExit` event, but if I can get a better idea...

Comment: if you're using a newer version of Delphi, you could check using TryStrToFloat http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/System.SysUtils.TryStrToFloat  if you're using an older version, then wrap StrToFloat into a function, and the the exception block, set the result to 0.00

Comment: Oops my bad I forget to precise: under Delphi 2007. Wrapping is a good idea!

Comment: @JohnEasley: If you are just going to default to 0.0, use `StrToFloatDef()` instead, which has been available since D6.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**TLDR** Don't seek a 'one size fits all' blanket replacement option for the exception swallowers. Rather identify the specific problems you're trying to address in each case and ensure your code explicitly conveys its intent.

---

You may already know this, but I want to highlight some problems in the code presented. Understanding these problems yields distinct possibilities in what could go wrong. It helps to think about what behaviour you want in each case, and you should ensure your code explicitly reflects your decisions making it easier to read and maintain.

```
begin
  ...  
  try
    _value := StrToFloat(Edit.Text);
  except
  end; 
  ...
end;
```

The reason for the exception swallowing is explained as:

> As the TEdit might be empty, there should be no error message in such a situation.

1. With reference to the quoted comment: the exception swallower is *hiding more* than the stated intention. Invalid characters or a value that 'doesn't fit' and cannot be stored, would also raise exceptions that are summarily swallowed. This may be acceptable, but my guess is that these possibilities were more likely overlooked. Although far less likely, even exceptions totally unrelated to the conversion itself would be swallowed: such 'out of memory' or 'stack overflow'.
2. If an exception is raised in `StrToFloat` then assignment to `_value` is skipped. So it retains whatever its previous value happened to be.

   - This is not necessarily bad ***if*** its previous value is *predictable* ***and*** its previous value is *acceptable* for purpose.
   - But the value might not be predictable. Especially if it's an uninitialised local variable: it will have whatever happened to be on the stack at the time of the call. But you might also find that if it's a member of an object that it has a predictable but very difficult to discern previous value - making the code hard to read.
   - Even when it seems predictable, that value might not be "fit for purpose". Consider a form reading edit control values into properties on a button click. On first click the value was valid an property set. But on second click, value has been changed and property is not updated - yet it holds the clearly no longer valid value from the first click.
3. Finally, the most important concern is that if something goes wrong, the method that swallowed the exception ***cannot*** perform its task correctly. And other code that called the method (yet presumably relies on its correct behaviour) is blissfully unaware of the problem. Usually, this simply leads to a delayed error (which is much more difficult to fix). The root problem is hidden, so something goes wrong later. E.g.

   - Another method called the above expecting `_value` would be *correctly* assigned for some calculations.
   - The root error is hidden, so `_value` is incorrect.
   - Later calculation might produce `EDivByZero` or simply an incorrect result.
   - If incorrect result is persisted, the problem could remain hidden for years.

---

As mentioned before, how you fix the exception swallowers depends on your intent in each case (yes it's more work this way, but if you're fixing something it helps to fix it "properly").

#### Option 1

Do you really need to hide the fact that the "user made a mistake"?

*Assuming there are no other error handling mistakes in the code:*

- If user types "Hello" an exception will be raised, aborting the current operation. The user will see an error message stating `'Hello' is not a valid floating point value.`.
- Similarly not entering any value will result in: `'' is not a valid floating point value.`.

So certainly an option worth serious consideration is to: Simply delete the swallower.

```
begin
  ...  
  _value := StrToFloat(Edit.Text);
  ...
end;
```

#### Option 2

Since you're specifically concerned about raising an error when the `TEdit` *empty* you may be able to consider this as a special case.

- It might make sense to assume that when the user doesn't provide a value, `0` is a suitable default. **NB! Only do this if it *really is* an appropriate default. (See next point)**
- The value might be optional. In which case you don't want to report an error if something optional is not provided. Rather set a flag associated with the value that indicates it was not provided. (NB: Don't overload a ***valid*** value to indicate 'value not provided'; otherwise you won't be able to differentiate the two.)

In either case it's worthwhile handling the special case explicitly and allowing default error reporting to kick in otherwise.

```
begin
  ...  
  if (Trim(Edit.Text) = '') then
    _value := 0
    //or _valueIsNull := True;
  else
    _value := StrToFloat(Edit.Text);
  ...
end;
```

NOTE: You could of course also set a default of `0` in the control value in advance of the user updating controls. This makes the default clear to the user. And if the user *chooses to **delete*** the default, then reverting to option 1 informs the user that this is not allowed.

#### Option 3

The default error handling can be made more user-friendly. E.g. You might want a more informative message, ensure focus is set to the 'error control', or set a hint message.

In this case you'd want to use `TryStrToFloat()` as per David's answer. *As far as I can tell this was introduced in Delphi 7. (In older versions you may be able to use `TextToFloat()`. Examine the implementation of `StrToFloat()` for an example.)*

The following is but one possible example to demonstrate how you could write some simple utility functions to encapsulate your specific needs and make your special handling of certain cases explicit.

```
type
  TDefaultMode = (dmNone, dmDefaultEmptyValue, dmDefaultInvalidValue);

function ReadFloatFromEditControl(AEdit: TCustomEdit; ADefaultMode: TDefaultMode = dmNone; ADefaultValue: Double = 0.0): Double;
begin
  if not TryStrToFloat(AEdit.Text, Result) then
  begin
    if (ADefaultMode = dmDefaultEmptyValue) and (Trim(AEdit.Text) = '') then
      Result := ADefaultValue
    else if (ADefaultMode = dmDefaultInvalidValue) then
      Result := ADefaultValue
    else
    begin
      AEdit.SetFocus;
      raise EConvertError.Create('['+AEdit.Text+'] is an invalid floating point value.');
    end;
    {If default is applied, replace value in edit control}
    AEdit.Text := FloatToStr(Result);
  end;
end;

{Use as follows:}
v1 := ReadFloatFromEditControl(Edit1);
v2 := ReadFloatFromEditControl(Edit2, dmDefaultInvalidValue);
v3 := ReadFloatFromEditControl(Edit3, dmDefaultEmptyValue, 1.0);
```

Comment: Well done for taking the time to engage at a deeper level

Comment: Thank you. The fact that @paradise wants to clean up bad exception handling is a promising sign. I'll consider it time well spent if anyone manages to write cleaner more maintainable code as result.

Comment: Thanks for your complete answer @CraigYoung. I had most of your points in mind, ie assignment to `_value` that is checked elsewhere, another error handler for detecting invalid chars (your "Hello" example), etc. Option 2 fits better in my case (indeed the value might be optional, that's why user should leave an empty Edit without getting any message) but I like your Option 3 handler as well.

Answer (score 5):

You should use [`TryStrToFloat`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.TryStrToFloat):

```
if TryStrToFloat(Edit1.Text, _value) then
  // do something with _value
```

This is a function that returns a boolean indicating success of the conversion. The converted value, on success, is returned in an out parameter.

Comment: `StrToFloatDef` might also work in this case, depending on whatever this _something_ actually is.

Comment: I'm under Delphi 2007 so no `TryStrToFloat` available, but I could implement such a helper method ideed.

Comment: OK, but the answer is still valid for the question as asked, especially for other readers. Wrapping this up is well worthwhile. Don't want to repeat yourself too much.

Comment: @paradise: I checked, `TryStrToFloat()` does exist in D2007, in the `SysUtils` unit. There are **6 overloads** of it, actually - 3 overloads to handle `Extended`, `Double`, and `Single` output, and 3 overloads that do the same with support for `TFormatSettings` input.

Comment: Great news @RemyLebeau, I didn't knew that one.